# Division Solution Results in Whole Numbers Only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently writing a math problem program for a school project. I'm stuck on a particular part for division portion.

The numerator needs to always be larger than the denominator, yet the quotient always needs to be a whole number. The program is supposed to generate numbers randomly from 1-20.

Ex: 14 / 7 = 2
Numerator > Denominator = Result is a whole number, not a decimal.

Thanks!

Note: we are not allowed to round our answers. The division always has to result in a whole number.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to generate problems that result in whole number quotients? If so, try multiplying 2 integers, use the product as the dividend, and one of the integers as the divisor.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pick a numerator and a denominator that will result in an answer that is a whole number? If so, just pick any whole numbers to be the denominator and **the result**,. and multiply them together to get the numerator.

Comment: Apologies, I clarified above. I need the numerator to always be a great number than the denominator, and the quotient needs to be a whole number result each time.

Comment: @DieHard345 Then I think you can use the suggestion in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare your variable as an Integer and then do the division. If you don't care about the remainder or how it is rounded. For example from Microsoft:

```
 Dim resultValue As Integer
 resultValue = 11 \ 4 'result is 2
 resultValue = 9 \ 3 'result is 3
 resultValue = 100 \ 3 'result is 33
 resultValue = 67 \ -3 'result is -22
```

If you want to round up or down you could simply do a double as your result value and set a new value as an integer. For example:

```
Public Function RoundUp(ByVal num) As Long
    If num >= 0 Then
        If num = Int(num) Then
            RoundUp = num
        Else
            RoundUp = Int(num) + 1
        End If
    ElseIf num < 0 Then
        RoundUp = Int(num)
    End If
End Function

Public Function RoundDown(ByVal num) As Long
    RoundDown = Fix(num)
    If num >= 0 Then
        If num = Int(num) Then
            RoundDown = num
        Else
            RoundDown = Int(num)
        End If
    ElseIf Number < 0 Then
        RoundDown = Int(num) - 1
    End If
End Function
```

Edit. Is this what you are looking for?

```
Public Function InputIsValid(ByVal numerator, ByVal denominator) As Boolean
    If (numerator > denominator) AND (numerator Mod denominator = 0) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Brandon! Thanks for the answer. I should have clarified further - we are not allowed to round the answers. The answer always has to result in a whole number answer - no decimals allowed :(

Comment: @DieHard345 So you want a function that returns if a numerator divided by its denominator is a whole number?

Comment: Your edit is exactly what I was looking for! I had something similar, but am confused on how to incorporate that into generating the numbers for the user to solve. Any additional input on that? Apologies, relatively new to VB

Answer (score 0):

To find a result in correct way then you can use following code

```
        Dim num, den As Double
        If num Mod den = 0 Then
            MsgBox("whole number")
        Else
            MsgBox("decemial number")
        End If
```